# Notice: Undefined index - Parse Server < WordPress Plugin

Tags: php, json, wordpress, parse-server

I'm making a plugin to connect WordPress to a Parse Server instance. When I tried to excute the plugin it threw the error below:

```
Notice: Undefined index: wp-parse-api-page in .../wp-content/plugins/WP-Plugin/includes/class-wp-parse-api-admin-settings.php on line 31
```

Here is the code...

**Line 31** `$_GET['wp-parse-api-page']= (int)$_GET['wp-parse-api-page'];`

I would appreciate it if someone could point out what I'm missing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure in url pass this query-string variable **wp-parse-api-page** and in code add condition before use query-string variable.

```
if(isset($_GET['wp-parse-api-page']))
   $_GET['wp-parse-api-page']= (int)$_GET['wp-parse-api-page'];
```

So this warning won't come.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the item in the array with the key `wp-parse-api-page`. Check your url for `?wp-parse-api-page=`.